# I am getting a SyntaxError in my model.py where could be the issue with my code

Tags: django, python-2.7, fedora-25

iam writing my code in model.py but this error that i getting in my development server.Any suggestions are welcome.I have followed previous suggections in stackflow but i can't get any answer that is solving my code. 
Error:the code below is the error i am getting.

```
 Unhandled exception in thread started by <function wrapper at 0x7fe6d63e4938>
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 227, in wrapper
        fn(*args, **kwargs)
      File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 117, in inner_run
        autoreload.raise_last_exception()
      File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 250, in raise_last_exception
        six.reraise(*_exception)
      File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 227, in wrapper
        fn(*args, **kwargs)
      File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 27, in setup
        apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
      File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 108, in populate
        app_config.import_models()
      File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 202, in import_models
        self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
      File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
        __import__(name)
      File "/home/harrugg2/projects/django/church/tithe/models.py", line 24
        def print(self):
                ^
    SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

below is my code for model.py

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from __future__ import unicode_literals
from django.utils import timezone
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
class tithe(models.models):
    genarationNo = models(ForeignKey('generationNo.User'))
    memberid = models.IntField()
    membername = models.VacharField()
    tithe = models.IntField()
    combinedoffering = models.IntField(max_length=45)
    campmeetingoffering = models.IntField(IntField=45)
    churchbuilding = models.IntField(max_length=45)
    conference = models.IntField(max_length=45)
    localchurch = models.IntField(max_length=45)
    funds = models.IntField(max_length=45)
    total = models.IntField(max_length=45)
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(
            default=timezone.now)
    printed_date = models.DateTimeField(
            blank=True, null=True)

    def print(self):
        self.printed_date = timezone.now()
        self.save()

    def __str__(self):
        return self.generationNo

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ["generationNo","IntField"]
        ordering = ["printed_date","membername"]
```

Comment: Please do not using standard function of [`print`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#print), you should change to another name..

Answer (score 3):

`print` is a keyword of the language. It is reserved and can not be used as an identifier. [See this](http://zetcode.com/lang/python/keywords/).

Answer (score 1):

As others said, `print` is not a good name for a function but there is something else strange with your code.
In `unique_together` you are referencing a field that does not exist.

Comment: @noobunatrixx a you refering to this field   `unique_together = ["generationNo","IntField"]`

Comment: Actually, neither exists, because there's a typo in the field name,  `genarationNo`.

Comment: @harri Yes. "IntField" does not match any of the fields on your model. Check out the django docs on `unique_together`. Also, there are many django tutorials online that can help you better understand this stuff.

Comment: @noobinatrixxx I solved the issue  now it's working  fyn  thanks  for your  follow up